# Installing IE under linux Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, internet, wine, browser

I want to install IE browser in ubuntu 10.10. I have done it using wine but
its not working. Is there any possibility to install IE?

Comment: what do you mean not working? which version IE and wine you are trying? Please include with your question if you find any error message.

Comment: Whyyyyyyyyyyy!?

Answer (score 2):

1) First a question - WHY do you want IE on Ubuntu?

2) If you install PlayOnLinux (a front end for Wine) you can install IE6 and/or IE7 under Wine.

3) Firefox can pretend to be IE it you use the add-on called "User Agent Switcher"

Comment: Re 1) - I presume Kush is a web designer or front end developer, and consequently needs to know their work functions in IE.

Comment: @Macha: Testing on WINE is **not** a substitute for testing IE on Windows. I've done it before but there are many unique issues with IE on WINE that are non-issues on it's native platform. Browser testing should be done in a virtual machine not an emulated platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks). You can also take a look at this page:
http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-69ca5e820c6eef64196e1830bf7f09521c2a4843